# Right OR Wrong : Declaring array and calling function on same line, javaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to get the array response from some function and want to store response on the same line. So what are some others way to perform same thing ?

Can i write this ,

`var x[]=returning_array();`

Or i have to do this ?

```
var x=[];
x=returning_array();
```

Comment: Why not try it and find out?

Comment: Both are wrong. The second way will work, but not for the reason you think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this

```js
var x = returning_array();
console.log(x);
function returning_array(argument) {
  return [1,2,3,4];
}
```

Comment: So , does javascript automatically make the variable to its assigned value's type ?

Answer (score 0):

You don't declare the type of the variable in Javascript by default. So assuming the function `returning_array` returns an array, you can declare your variable like so:

```
var x = returning_array();
```

For more info, have a look at the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var).